# Why add 25 to cube position in three.js example?

Tags: three.js

The three.js [Voxel painter example](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_interactive_voxelpainter.html#L129) adds 25 to the position of every voxel. Why is this? When I remove the `addScale` call, I can see some of the grid through the cube. Why can I see the grid through the cube when it's positioned at 0,0,0 and why does adding 25 fix this?

With:

[image]

Without:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the lines 52-55

```
var rollOverGeo = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry( 50, 50, 50 );
rollOverMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xff0000, opacity: 0.5, transparent: true } );
rollOverMesh = new THREE.Mesh( rollOverGeo, rollOverMaterial );
scene.add( rollOverMesh );
```

The cube is created with width, height and depth of 50. The way three js works is that position of the cube is really the position of the centre of the cube, so when the cube is created at (0, 0, 0) by default, it is cut in half by the XY plane, like your second screenshot. The reason that you can see the grid is because half of the cube is below the grid.

They probably want the cube to appear on top of the XY plane(like the first screenshot) so they push it up by 50 / 2 units or 25 units.

Answer (score 2):

You're being fooled by the projection from the current camera position, which just happens to make it look as if the cube is aligned with its base on the zero-plane.

In fact, the untranslated cube is centered at the origin, and the grid lines are being clipped by its faces.  None of the faces on that cube are on a grid line.  By adding a translation, it moves the object's center so that it falls halfway between all grid positions (including the vertical axis, which has no grid displayed).  Since the cube's size is 50, that then means all faces are aligned with the grid.